# implementation of lms adaptive filter in matlab

Tags: matlab

How does `adaptfilt.lms` work in matlab? Anybody knows what the structure of the filter will be when we create and use

```
mu = 0.09;            % LMS step size        
ha = adaptfilt.lms(32,mu);       
[y,e] = filter(ha,x,d);
```

where d-desired output, x-actual output?
x and d are of size 2048 x 1, i need the structure of the filter.

Comment: This would adapt an FIR filter. Is this what you are looking for?

Answer (score 0):

This is a FIR (Finite Impulse Response) filter. The structure is the following:

```
y(k) = b(1).x(k)+...+b(n).x(k-n+1)
```

Where `b` is a polynomial, found as `ha.Coefficients`, after the `lms` method has adapted to the data.